How to connect separated meshes from one model without combining the grid?
I have .stl model and need to separate outer part to remesh it and to add some modifiers. After it I have two meshes with circle edges with different amount of nodes.If I combine grid with Ctrl + J, models become broken.
I need to combine then to get good topology without holes to generate .gcode without problems.


What do you mean "models become broken". Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

I mean, that topology of holes and some elements becomes terrible. First part grid consists of triangles, second - from quads. I need to remesh on part to ideal squares to make exact result.
